# Rank function always returns the same values for each group?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Goal: to find the **top 200 tracks for the past 3 months**.
*consumer data* for each track to be **daily**.

I have used

```
RANK () OVER(PARTITION BY report_date ORDER BY SUM(num_streams))
```

What I am afraid of is that it will return me **different top 200 for each day** and **I don't want that**.

I want the **top 200 stay the same for every day**. 
But with different consumer data each day.

Any idea?

I am using AWS REDSHIFT

I want this:

```
Day       Track_Title       Consumer_counts       Rank
Jul 1      Halo               600                  1
Jul 1      old town road      200                  2
Jul 1      heartbeat          180                  3
Jul 2      Halo               500                  1
Jul 2      old town road      300                  2
Jul 2      heartbeat          400                  3
```

But instead I get that

```
 Day       Track_Title       Consumer_counts       Rank
Jul 1      Halo               600                  1
Jul 1      old town road      200                  2
Jul 1      heartbeat          180                  3
Jul 2      Halo               500                  1
Jul 2      wish you were here 400                  2
Jul 2      old town road      300                  3
```

Comment: Sample data expected results would help clarify this question.  As it stands it's a bit vague for me.

Comment: @xQbert check this now

Comment: Ok so get the top 200 not by day initially but instead for the period requested.  Then go back and get the daily counts.  that way the 200 remain static for each day; and the counts are specific to the top 200.  Put another way.  Step 1 Identify the top 200 tracks over the 3 months.  Step 2 get the daily counts for each of those 200 tracks.  Now all 200 tracks will remain consistent; and the appropriate daily counts will work for each.

Comment: @xQbert Okay I will try that. It is more complicated than that, and I was trying to avoid this way, but it looks like there is no really a function similar to rank that will keep the values static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top 200 tracks over 3 months and then get a daily count that include only the selected 200 tracks, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT top 200 --To get the top 200 tracks over 3 months
t.track,
RANK () OVER(PARTITION BY t.track ORDER BY SUM(t.num_streams))
INTO #tempTable
FROM 
(SELECT track, num_streams
FROM MyTable
WHERE report_date BETWEEN "2019-01-01" and "2019-04-01") t

SELECT  --To get the top 200 tracks for the selected date.
mt.day,
mt.track,
SUM(mt.num_streams)
RANK () OVER(PARTITION BY mt.report_date ORDER BY SUM(mt.num_streams))
FROM #tempTable tt
INNER JOIN MyTable mt on tt.track = mt.track
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an aggregation query

```
select Track_Title, sum(Consumer_counts) as total
       rank() over (order by sum(Consumer_counts) desc) as ranking
from t
where report_date >= current_date - interval '3 month'
group by Track_Title
order by total desc
limit 200;
```

If you want the detail by day, then I would suggest joining this back in:

```
with top200 as (
      select Track_Title, sum(Consumer_counts) as total
             rank() over (order by sum(Consumer_counts) desc) as ranking
      from t
      where report_date >= current_date - interval '3 month'
      group by Track_Title
      order by total desc
      limit 200
     )
select t.*, top200.ranking
from t join
     top200
     on t.Track_Title = top200.Track_Title
order by t.report_date, top200.ranking;
```